# "Please set up mail account in order to send email" Error in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, email

I try to send an email through my app but I got an error that called

> "Please set up mail account in order to send email".

My code block is below.

```
import MessageUI

@IBAction func emailTapped(_ sender: Any) {   

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["abc@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in })
    }  
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Swift.Error?){
    controller.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in } 
}
```

Comment: Have you setup an email account on the device you are testing on?

Comment: And why do you do all the work to set up the mail controller before you do the check to see if you can actually send email?

Answer (score 4):

The code looks good enough (though it can be improved), you need to setup your email account on the device you are using.

```
import MessageUI
    @IBAction func emailTapped(_ sender: Any) {  

            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() { 
                let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
                mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
                mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["abc@gmail.com"])
                mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
                mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

                self.present(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in })
            }

        }

        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Swift.Error?){
            controller.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in }

        }
```

Now, search for the `Settings` app on your iPhone, then goto `Mail` -> `Accounts` -> `Add Account` to setup a email account on the phone.
You can check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3QCINnEl-0).

Comment: The settings up of a mail account is on your iOS device not Xcode. This settings is not available in the simulator only on a real device.